# Segmentation fault while comparing elements in a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, fifo, page-replacement

This program tries to simulate FIFO and LRU page replacement. I am trying to implement a simple queue using a [dynamically allocated array](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html#dynamic) for the FIFO queue. I want the "page" to be stored in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
 * Some compile-time constants.
 */

#define REPLACE_NONE 0
#define REPLACE_FIFO 1
#define REPLACE_LRU  2
#define REPLACE_SECONDCHANCE 3
#define REPLACE_OPTIMAL 4


#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH 60
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 100


/*
 * Some function prototypes to keep the compiler happy.
 */
int setup(void);
int teardown(void);
int output_report(void);
long resolve_address(long, int);
void error_resolve_address(long, int);


/*
 * Variables used to keep track of the number of memory-system events
 * that are simulated.
 */
int page_faults = 0;
int mem_refs    = 0;
int swap_outs   = 0;
int swap_ins    = 0;


/*
 * Page-table information. You may want to modify this in order to
 * implement schemes such as SECONDCHANCE. However, you are not required
 * to do so.
 */
struct page_table_entry *page_table = NULL;
struct page_table_entry {
    long page_num;
    int dirty;
    int free;
};


/*
 * These global variables will be set in the main() function. The default
 * values here are non-sensical, but it is safer to zero out a variable
 * rather than trust to random data that might be stored in it -- this
 * helps with debugging (i.e., eliminates a possible source of randomness
 * in misbehaving programs).
 */

int size_of_frame = 0;  /* power of 2 */
int size_of_memory = 0; /* number of frames */
int page_replacement_scheme = REPLACE_NONE;

long *queue;

void add_end(long page_num){
    for(int i=0; i<size_of_memory; i++){
        if(queue[i] == NULL){
            queue[i] = page_num;
            break;
        }
    }
}

long peek_front(){
    return queue[0];
}

void remove_front(){
    for(int i=0; i<size_of_memory; i++){
        queue[i] = queue[i+1];
    }
}

// typedef struct page_in_queue page_in_queue;
// struct page_in_queue {
//     long page_num;
//     page_in_queue *next;
// };

// page_in_queue *new_page(){
//     page_in_queue *new_page;
//     new_page = (page_in_queue *) malloc(sizeof(page_in_queue));
//     new_page->next = NULL;
//     return new_page;
// }

// page_in_queue *add_end(page_in_queue *queue, page_in_queue *page){
//     page_in_queue *curr;

//     if (queue == NULL) {
//         page->next = NULL;
//         return page;
//     }

//     for (curr = queue; curr->next != NULL; curr = curr->next);
//     curr->next = page;
//     page->next = NULL;
//     return queue;
// }

// page_in_queue *peek_front(page_in_queue *queue) {
//     return queue;
// }

// page_in_queue *remove_front(page_in_queue *queue){
//     if (queue == NULL) {
//         return NULL;
//     }

//     page_in_queue *new_front_page = queue->next;

//     free(queue);

//     return new_front_page;
// }

long *list;

void add(long page_num){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size_of_memory; i++){
        list[i] = list[i+1];
    }
    list[i] = page_num;
}

long peek_least_used(){
    return list[0];
}

/*
 * Function to convert a logical address into its corresponding 
 * physical address. The value returned by this function is the
 * physical address (or -1 if no physical address can exist for
 * the logical address given the current page-allocation state.
 */

long resolve_address(long logical, int memwrite)
{
    int i;
    long page, frame;
    long offset;
    long mask = 0;
    long effective;

    /* Get the page and offset */
    page = (logical >> size_of_frame);

    for (i=0; i<size_of_frame; i++) {
        mask = mask << 1;
        mask |= 1;
    }
    offset = logical & mask;

    if (page_replacement_scheme == 2){
        add(page);
    }

    /* Find page in the inverted page table. */
    frame = -1;
    for ( i = 0; i < size_of_memory; i++ ) {
        if (!page_table[i].free && page_table[i].page_num == page) {
            frame = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    /* If frame is not -1, then we can successfully resolve the
     * address and return the result. */
    if (frame != -1) {
        effective = (frame << size_of_frame) | offset;
        return effective;
    }


    /* If we reach this point, there was a page fault. Find
     * a free frame. */
    page_faults++;

    for ( i = 0; i < size_of_memory; i++) {
        if (page_table[i].free) {
            frame = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // page_in_queue *temp_page;
    // page_in_queue *queue;
    long rem_page;

    /* If we found a free frame, then patch up the
     * page table entry and compute the effective
     * address. Otherwise return -1.
     */
    if (frame != -1) {
        page_table[frame].page_num = page;
        page_table[i].free = FALSE;
        swap_ins++;
        if (page_replacement_scheme == 1){
            // temp_page = new_page();
            // temp_page->page_num = page;
            add_end(page);
        }
        effective = (frame << size_of_frame) | offset;
        return effective;
    } 
    else {
        if (page_replacement_scheme == 1){
            rem_page = peek_front();
            for ( i = 0; i < size_of_memory; i++){
                if(page_table[i].page_num == rem_page){
                    page_table[i].page_num = page;
                    page_table[i].free = FALSE;
                    page_table[i].dirty = memwrite;
                    swap_ins++;
                    if(page_table[i].dirty == 1){
                        swap_outs++;
                    }
                    frame = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            remove_front();
            effective = (frame << size_of_frame) | offset;
            return effective;
        }

        if (page_replacement_scheme == 2){
            long temp = peek_least_used();
            for ( i = 0; i < size_of_memory; i++){
                if(page_table[i].page_num == temp){
                    page_table[i].page_num = page;
                    page_table[i].free = FALSE;
                    page_table[i].dirty = memwrite;
                    swap_ins++;
                    if(page_table[i].dirty == 1){
                        swap_outs++;
                    }
                    frame = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            effective = (frame << size_of_frame) | offset;
            return effective;
        }

        if (page_replacement_scheme == 3){

        }
    }
}



/*
 * Super-simple progress bar.
 */
void display_progress(int percent)
{
    int to_date = PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH * percent / 100;
    static int last_to_date = 0;
    int i;

    if (last_to_date < to_date) {
        last_to_date = to_date;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    printf("Progress [");
    for (i=0; i<to_date; i++) {
        printf(".");
    }
    for (; i<PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH; i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("] %3d%%", percent);
    printf("\r");
    fflush(stdout);
}


int setup()
{
    int i;

    page_table = (struct page_table_entry *)malloc(
        sizeof(struct page_table_entry) * size_of_memory
    );

    if (page_table == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Simulator error: cannot allocate memory for page table.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i=0; i<size_of_memory; i++) {
        page_table[i].free = TRUE;
    }

    return -1;
}


int teardown()
{

    return -1;
}


void error_resolve_address(long a, int l)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fprintf(stderr, 
        "Simulator error: cannot resolve address 0x%lx at line %d\n",
        a, l
    );
    exit(1);
}


int output_report()
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Memory references: %d\n", mem_refs);
    printf("Page faults: %d\n", page_faults);
    printf("Swap ins: %d\n", swap_ins);
    printf("Swap outs: %d\n", swap_outs);

    return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* For working with command-line arguments. */
    int i;
    char *s;

    /* For working with input file. */
    FILE *infile = NULL;
    char *infile_name = NULL;
    struct stat infile_stat;
    int  line_num = 0;
    int infile_size = 0;

    /* For processing each individual line in the input file. */
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    long addr;
    char addr_type;
    int  is_write;

    /* For making visible the work being done by the simulator. */
    int show_progress = FALSE;

    /* Process the command-line parameters. Note that the
     * REPLACE_OPTIMAL scheme is not required for A#3.
     */
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strncmp(argv[i], "--replace=", 9) == 0) {
            s = strstr(argv[i], "=") + 1;
            if (strcmp(s, "fifo") == 0) {
                page_replacement_scheme = REPLACE_FIFO;
            } else if (strcmp(s, "lru") == 0) {
                page_replacement_scheme = REPLACE_LRU;
            } else if (strcmp(s, "secondchance") == 0) {
                page_replacement_scheme = REPLACE_SECONDCHANCE;
            } else if (strcmp(s, "optimal") == 0) {
                page_replacement_scheme = REPLACE_OPTIMAL;
            } else {
                page_replacement_scheme = REPLACE_NONE;
            }
        } else if (strncmp(argv[i], "--file=", 7) == 0) {
            infile_name = strstr(argv[i], "=") + 1;
        } else if (strncmp(argv[i], "--framesize=", 12) == 0) {
            s = strstr(argv[i], "=") + 1;
            size_of_frame = atoi(s);
        } else if (strncmp(argv[i], "--numframes=", 12) == 0) {
            s = strstr(argv[i], "=") + 1;
            size_of_memory = atoi(s);
            if (page_replacement_scheme == 1){
                queue = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long)*size_of_memory);
            }
            if (page_replacement_scheme == 2){
                list = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long)*size_of_memory);
            }
        } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "--progress") == 0) {
            show_progress = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if (infile_name == NULL) {
        infile = stdin;
    } else if (stat(infile_name, &infile_stat) == 0) {
        infile_size = (int)(infile_stat.st_size);
        /* If this fails, infile will be null */
        infile = fopen(infile_name, "r");  
    }


    if (page_replacement_scheme == REPLACE_NONE ||
        size_of_frame <= 0 ||
        size_of_memory <= 0 ||
        infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, 
            "usage: %s --framesize=<m> --numframes=<n>", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, 
            " --replace={fifo|lru|optimal} [--file=<filename>]\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    setup();

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LEN-1, infile)) {
        line_num++;
        if (strstr(buffer, ":")) {
            sscanf(buffer, "%c: %lx", &addr_type, &addr);
            if (addr_type == 'W') {
                is_write = TRUE;
            } else {
                is_write = FALSE;
            }

            if (resolve_address(addr, is_write) == -1) {
                error_resolve_address(addr, line_num);
            }
            mem_refs++;
        } 

        if (show_progress) {
            display_progress(ftell(infile) * 100 / infile_size);
        }
    }
    

    teardown();
    output_report();

    fclose(infile);

    exit(0);
}
```

The file is saved as virtmem.c. This is the makefile:

```
#
# "makefile" for the virtual-memory simulation.
#

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -g

all: virtmem

virtmem.o: virtmem.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) virtmem.c

virtmem: virtmem.o
    $(CC) virtmem.o -o virtmem

clean:
    rm -rf *.o virtmem
```

After running the "make" command, I run the executable with these inputs

```
./virtmem --framesize=12 --numframes=100 --replace=fifo --file=traces/ls_out.txt --progress
```

But it is giving a segmentation fault at the conditional "if(queue[i] == NULL)", saying the memory location cannot be accessed. The gdb output is as follows:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554bea in add_end (page_num=34158723704) at virtmem.c:80
80              if(queue[i] == (long)0){
(gdb) print queue[i]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb)
```

Comment: You haven't addressed some of the comments from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084450/segmentation-fault-while-using-dynamically-allocated-array). `sizeof(size_of_frame)` is likely wrong as one of the comments say. Not sure what  you are trying to do there. Should probably be `sizeof(long)`.

Comment: And is that really the full code? The debugger msg says the error is on line 80 but the code shown does not have that many lines and even the line of code shown in the debugger is different to the posted code. We need to see the **exact** code that produces that exact error. Repeating what others have already requested from your multiple times: please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the code to be my actual program and also included the makefile

Comment: `--numframes=100 --replace=fifo` try swapping the order of these two parameters. Because the memory allocation is triggered by the `--numframes` but that needs the replacement algorithm set before the correct `malloc` is called.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that actually cleared up many of my doubts